# Pits and Pores in Vascular Tissue

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

What purpose is served by the pits and pores in xylem and phloem cells? I cant find what purpose that these components serve in the vascular tissues in plants

Comment: Welcome to Biology S.E.! If you need additional assistance with the site, please visit [The Help Center](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Welcome! Could you provide a reference to where you have encountered these features? A picture might help too. Good luck.

Comment: those are on side walls of xylem? they allow side-wise flow of water. In cases a bubble blocks a xylem, through side-pits the water bypass. In many plants there are a sort of torus-margo structure that blocks the water-flow if side-flow crosses a limit.

Comment: In case of phloem, if the sieve tubes (which are metabolic-active and full of cytosol) did not contained pores in their tops and bottoms (sieve plates), it would have problem in transport, as-well, through fine pores in sieve plate there are cytoskeletal structures those possibly have some active role in transport. The sieve pores sometimes blocked by callose and P-protein, especially to resist stress like cut and bleed, and also in certain stages of dormancy.

Comment: Xylem vessels are wide and 'dead'  (empty, without any cytosol), to avoid the friction to drag water.

Comment: The main large holes and cavity (Xylem lumens) that we could see on TS (often on naked eye), exists because without them no flow of water will take place.

Comment: I'll write more elaborately in answer. I'll take time for that.